# Drag and Drop AS3 - Simple snap to original place

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, drag-and-drop

Creating a game
Drag and Drop type
There are no "target areas (as when you hover over a button, it plays the video)
I want when you drag the items to the videos, if you release the item, it snaps back to its place.

Here is the code that I have right now...

```
mc_d4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragD4);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragStop4);
function dragD4(e:Event):void {
mc_d4.startDrag();
}
function dragStop4(e:Event):void {
    mc_d4.stopDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save the location of the current dragged item somewhere. The easy solution would be to save it in a variable

```
var startPosition:Point;

mc_d4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragD4);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragStop4);

function dragD4(e:Event):void {
   mc_d4.startDrag();
   startPosition = new Point( mc_d4.x, mc_d4.y);
}

function dragStop4(e:Event):void {
   mc_d4.stopDrag();
   //set back or tween position

   mc_d4.x = startPosition.x;
   mc_d4.y = startPosition.y;

   startPosition = null;

}
```